# Scan row into slice

Tags: sql, go, slice

I want to Scan a sql.Row into a slice like so:

```
func printRows(rows *sql.Rows){
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var row = []interface{}{}
        err := rows.Scan(row...)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        r, err := json.Marshal(row)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println("row:", r);
    }
}
```

but I am getting this error:

> 2020/02/23 20:05:14 raw query: SELECT * FROM user_table  LIMIT 500
>   2020/02/23 20:05:14 sql: expected 6 destination arguments in Scan, not
>   0

anyone know how to make this generic without using a slice?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using a slice? You can check how many columns are returned (```len(rows.Columns())```) and then that to build your slice. [This post](http://go-database-sql.org/varcols.html) has more info.

Comment: if it's that simple can you just add an answer here? thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507531/is-golangs-sql-package-incapable-of-ad-hoc-exploratory-queries), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102725/go-sql-driver-get-interface-column-values), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435455/handling-dynamic-queries-cant-scan-into-struct), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477941/read-select-columns-into-string-in-go), ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
cols, err := rows.Columns() // Remember to check err afterwards
vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
for i, _ := range cols {
    vals[i] = new(string)
}

for rows.Next() {
    err = rows.Scan(vals...)
}
```

on the internet they say you can use:

```
    vals[i] = new(sql.RawBytes)
```

instead of

```
    vals[i] = new(string)
```

but I think (string) is fine, idk